# Why is calling an O(n) time algorithm on each node of a tree O(nlogn) time?

Tags: time-complexity, trees

Assume we have a balanced binary tree.

On *each* node, we call:

```python
def node_depths(root, depth):
    if not root:
        return 0
    return depth + node_depths(root.left, depth + 1) + \
      node_depths(root.right, depth + 1)
```

`node_depths` itself is O(n) time. But calling it on *each* node produces an O(nlogn) time algorithm.

Why is this? I would appreciate both/either an intuitive and a mathematical response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not false that `node_depths` is $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time for a tree $T$ of size $n$, but it is imprecise.

To be more precise, `node_depths(x, d)` has a complexity $\Theta(|T_x|)$ where $T_x$ is the subtree rooted in $x$ (can you see why?).

To prove the $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ bound, I will consider $T$ to be a perfect tree (it is easier that way, and the principle is the same for a balanced tree). Suppose $T$ is a perfect binary tree of size $n$ and height $h$.

- there is $1$ node of depth $0$, its subtree is of size $n$;
- there are $2$ nodes of depth $1$, their subtrees are of size $\frac{n}2$;
- there are $4$ nodes of depth $2$, their subtrees are of size $\frac{n}4$;
- …
- for $k\leqslant h$, there are $2^k$ nodes of depth $k$, their subtrees are of size $\frac{n}{2^k}$.

The total size of the subtrees is then:
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^h 2^k \times \frac{n}{2^k} = n\times (h+1) \in \mathcal{O}(n\log n)$$

Comment: Thank you, very nice.